# How do I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin to work?

Tags: ajax, header, xmlhttprequest

how do I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin to work?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

**My questions:**

- How do I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin to work?
- Is Access-Control-Allow-Origin supported by all major browsers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Check out Nicholos C. Zakas [intro](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/).

> There is a lot of solid support for
>   cross-domain Ajax in modern web
>   browsers, yet most developers are
>   still unaware of this powerful
>   capability. Usage requires just a
>   little bit of extra JavaScript work
>   and a little extra server-side work to
>   ensure that the correct headers are
>   being sent. IE8’s implementation lags
>   a bit behind the others in terms of
>   allowing advanced requests and
>   credentialed requests, but hopefully
>   support for CORS will continue to
>   improve.

Answer (score 2):

Go check out what Mozilla has up:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

This works in everything except IE (not sure about 9+)

Comment: According to your link IE 10 have no problem! But IE 8/9 require **XDomainRequest**